Making an api for tornado.com stock borker
I want to create an API for logging in and viewing things in the tornado.com stock exchange. I am using Python and trying to set the CSRF and send the data but I am getting a 404 error which I think means that my headers are bad.
import os
import pickle
import re
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def url_csrf():
    return "https://api.tornado.com/api/v1/util/csrf"


def url_login():
    return "https://api.tornado.com/users/sign_in"


class TornadoSession:
    """Class creating a session for Tornado."""
    def __init__(self, email, password, profile_path=None):
        """
        Initializes a new instance of the TornadoSession class.

        Args:
            email (str): Tornado login email.
            password (str): Tornado login password.
            profile_path (str, optional): The path where the user wants to save the cookie pkl file.
        """
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.persistent_session = False
        self.profile_path = profile_path
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        headers = session_headers()
        cookies = self.load_cookies()
        cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(cookies)
        self.session.cookies.update(cookies)
        
        # Fetch CSRF token
        response = self.session.get(url=url_csrf(), headers=headers)
        print(f"CSRF token request status: {response.status_code}")
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Error fetching CSRF token: {response.content}")
            return
        
        # Extract and set the _session_id cookie
        if 'Set-Cookie' in response.headers:
            set_cookie = response.headers['Set-Cookie']
            session_id = re.search(r'_session_id=([^;]+)', set_cookie).group(1)
            self.session.cookies.set('_session_id', session_id, domain='.tornado.com', path='/')
            print(f"Set _session_id cookie: {session_id}")
        else:
            print("Set-Cookie header not found in the response.")

        csrf_token = self.extract_csrf_token(response.content)
        
        # Prepare data for login
        data = {
            "user": {
                "email": self.email,
                "password": self.password,
                "remember_me": 1 if self.persistent_session else 0
            }
        }
        headers["x-csrf-token"] = csrf_token  # Add CSRF token to headers

        # Perform login
        response = self.session.post(
            url=url_login(),
            headers=headers,
            cookies=self.session.cookies,
            data=data,
        )
        print(f"Login request status: {response.status_code}")
        print(f"Login response content: {response.content}")

        # # Check if login was successful and extract Bearer token
        # if response.status_code == 200:
        #     response_json = response.json()
        #     if 'token' in response_json:  # Adjust key name based on API response
        #         self.token = response_json['token']
        #         print(f"Login successful. Bearer token: {self.token}")
        #     else:
        #         print("Login successful, but no token found in the response.")
        # else:
        #     print(f"Login failed with status code: {response.status_code}")

    def extract_csrf_token(self, content):
        """Extracts CSRF token from the response content."""
        # Convert the bytes to string and parse it
        content_str = content.decode('utf-8')
        csrf_match = re.search(r'csrf_token=&gt;&quot;(.*?)&quot;', content_str)
        if csrf_match:
            return csrf_match.group(1)
        else:
            raise ValueError("CSRF token not found in the response.")

    def load_cookies(self):
        """
        Checks if session cookies were saved.

        Returns:
            Dict: Dictionary of cookies.
        """
        cookies = {}
        directory = os.path.abspath(self.profile_path) if self.profile_path is not None else "."
        
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)

        for filename in os.listdir(directory):
            if filename.endswith(f"{self.email}.pkl"):
                filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
                    cookies = pickle.load(f)
        return cookies

    def save_cookies(self):
        """Saves session cookies to a file."""
        if self.profile_path is not None:
            directory = os.path.abspath(self.profile_path)
            if not os.path.exists(directory):
                os.makedirs(directory)
            path = os.path.join(self.profile_path, f"ft_cookies{self.email}.pkl")
        else:
            path = f"ft_cookies{self.email}.pkl"
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(self.session.cookies.get_dict(), f)
    
    def delete_cookies(self):    
        """Deletes the session cookies."""
        if self.profile_path is not None:
            path = os.path.join(self.profile_path, f"ft_cookies{self.email}.pkl")
        else:
            path = f"ft_cookies{self.email}.pkl"
        os.remove(path)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        Forwards unknown attribute access to session object.

        Args:
            name (str): The name of the attribute to be accessed.

        Returns:
            The value of the requested attribute from the session object.
        """
        return getattr(self.session, name)


    def session_headers(csrf=None):
        headers = {
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "Host": "api.tornado.com",
            "Referer": "https://tornado.com/app/login",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        }
        if csrf is not None:
            headers["x-csrf-token"] = csrf
        return headers


what am I doing wrong here the csrf comes back properly the set cookie gets set but nothing I saw other stock exchanges have this kind of API and I wanted to build one but it is not working.

"I am getting a 404 error which I think means that my headers are bad." it sounds like you are confusing 400 Bad Request with 404 Not Found
